# How to narrow my SQL select statement results

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table structure]

I am trying to narrow a select result to use within the 'where' section of a larger select statement. I only have the `catItem_id` values of 2 and 3, I need to get the prod_id 1 as it's the only row that posses both of the `catItem_id` values 2 & 3. I have tried the following (among many other attempts)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ep.prod_id 
FROM ext_Products AS ep
LEFT JOIN ext_categories AS ec ON ec.prod_id = ep.prod_id 
WHERE ec.catItem_id = 3 OR ec.catItem_id = 2
```

Returns prod_id 1 and 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT ep.prod_id 
FROM ext_Products AS ep
LEFT JOIN ext_categories AS ec ON ec.prod_id = ep.prod_id 
WHERE ec.catItem_id = 3
  AND ec.catItem_id = 2
```

Doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `catItem_id` cannot match two values on one row.  You want aggregation:

```
SELECT ep.prod_id 
from ext_Products ep JOIN
     ext_categories ec
     ON ec.prod_id = ep.prod_id 
WHERE ec.catItem_id IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY ep.prod_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is superfluous, because you need matches for the condition to be true.

Comment: Got it, thanks, I managed to work it out just before you posted.